# Enable data visualization (Prometheus stack) for Developer

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, eks

I'm Adding Pod Metrics Acess to EKS User, Here is the RBAC for AWS EKS with Role and RoleBinding, I had given most of the access to the Developer for their Usage,
Here is the Role defined for EKS:

```
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: dev-clusterrole
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["nodes", "nodes/metrics", "namespaces", "pods", "pods/portforward", "pods/metrics", "pods/exec", "secrets", "pods/log", "configmaps"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "portforward"]

  - apiGroups: ["apps"]
    resources: ["deployments", "daemonsets", "statefulsets", "replicasets"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "create"]

  - apiGroups: [ ""]
    resources: ["services", "services/portforward"]
    verbs: ["get", "watch", "list", "create", "portforward"]

  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["namespace"]
    verbs: ["get", "list"]    

  - apiGroups: ["autoscaling"]
    resources: ["horizontalpodautoscalers"]
    verbs: ["get", "list"]
```

I want to Give Pod Metrics access to the developer to view the memory and CPU of Pods Like this But It is not able to access after trying all the APIs.
[image]

NOTE: We are Using Graphana and Prometheus Stack for Monitoring.